# How to make grid div responsive and change style of it in Html Css

Tags: html, css, web

I have this kind of grid on my web. I want it to make responsive for mobiles and tablets. I attached the screenshot of what I have now and What I want. Thanks in Advance!
[image: Screenshot]

When I check this on my mobile, this happens :(

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make it look like this

[image: How I want it to be]

Here is my source code

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.box.big {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                            <div class="box">
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 2.15vw; ">AIRFREIGHT</p>
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200; font-size: 1.2vw; margin-bottom: 8px;">CHINA & EU to CIS via GYD<br>CHARTERING IN CHINA<br>EU TO GYD & SCO</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box">
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 2.15vw;">SEA FREIGHT</p>
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200; font-size: 1.2vw; margin-bottom: 8px;">SEA FREIGHT SERVICES VIA<br>POTI PORT, GE TO ASIA, EU<br>AND AMERICAS</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box">
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 2.15vw;">ROAD FREIGHT
                                </p>
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200; font-size: 1.2vw; margin-bottom: 8px;">EU TO CIS VIA SOUTHERN<br>CORRIDOR<br>LTL SERVICES FROM EU</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box">
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 2.15vw;">RAIL FREIGHT</p>
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200; font-size: 1.2vw; margin-bottom: 8px;">RAIL FREIGHT BETWEEN<br>AZE TO CIS AND POTI PORT<br>TERMINAL HANDLING IN AZ</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="box big">
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 2.15vw;">VALUE ADDED SERVICES</p>
                                <p style="font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200; font-size: 1.2vw; margin-bottom: 8px;">LTL SERVICES TO CIS<br>RORO / BREAKBULK SERVICES IN CASPIAN<br>VESSEL AGENCY SERVICES<br>CUSTOMS CLEARANCE AND TRANSIT FORMALITIES<br>APPLYING SPECIAL PERMITS & FEASIBILITY STUDY</p>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented and got the answer. All i had to do is add some css code. This will help alot)

```
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo{
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 48px;
  }
  .row{
    margin-top: 80px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box {
    margin:12px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  .box.big{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 16px;
  }

  .boxTextHeader{
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  .boxTextDescription{
    font-size: 3vw; 
  }
}
```

I've changed some html too by adding classes to make it more customizeable. This css is enough to get and idea.